# how to handle soft weight constraints in neural network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

Let us assume that there is a feedforward neural network with two layers. and weights of each layer are constrained such that sum of the weights is a constant value in each layer and their values are non-negative.  You may wonder why should we have such assumptions? Answer: I have an optimization problem with unknown variables that can be mapped to a neural network in that weights represent my variables that's why. Can anyone suggest to me a way to handle these constraints? for now, I just integrated these constraints into the cost function, though the way I did is not working very well. I just added the constraints to the main cost function using max. for example when A(x)<x I just added its cost as max(A(x)/x-1,0) to the main cost function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of mapping nn weights `Wi` to your problem, map `Constant * Softmax(Wi)` instead for each layer?

Comment: can you explain what you mean? because this is applied to the outputs, not to bare weights.